# Spring Boot Proxy via HttpClient doesn't work

Tags: spring-boot, proxy, httpclient

I'm trying to setup a WebClient connection in Spring Boot using a proxy. My implementation looks like the following:

```
final WebClient.Builder webclientBuilder = WebClient.builder();

final HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create();
httpClient.proxy(proxy -> proxy
                    .type(Proxy.HTTP)
                    .host(proxyName)
                    .port(Integer.parseInt(proxyPort)));

    final ReactorClientHttpConnector connector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient);
    webclientBuilder.clientConnector(connector);

final WebClient webClient = webclientBuilder
        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
        .build();
```

After running it and sending an API call, I receive a "Connection timed out: no further information". I should get back a Bad Request (in case my call is wrong), but I don't.

Is the implementation wrong?
the proxyName is written like this: "proxy.blabla.de"

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error and comparing I found a solution working for me:

```
String baseUrl = "https://mybaseurl";
String proxyName = "proxy.blabla.de";
int proxyPort = 1234;

public InitResponse addAccount() {

    //  for logging purposes, nothing to do with the proxy
    LOGGER.info("LOGGER.info: addAccount()");
    final InitRequest request = buildRequest();

    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create()
                    .proxy(proxy -> proxy.type(Proxy.HTTP)
                    .host(proxyName)
                    .port(proxyPort));

    ReactorClientHttpConnector conn = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient);
    WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder().clientConnector(conn).baseUrl(baseUrl).build();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

When you create new HttpClient using `create()` method, **it doesn't return builder** for it, but **actual client**
And other methods which set it up, like `proxy`, `followRedirect` and so on are actually return **clones** of this HttpClient

So you either have to **use "builder" chain approach,** or **rewrite your variable** before passing it to `WebClient.Builder.clientConnector()` method

Like so:

```java
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create().
    followRedirect(true);

// this is crucial
httpClient = httpClient.responseTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60));
```

The author never tried to explain what is the actual reason behind HttpClient not working...